# How to learn the associativity (number of way) of the TLB?

Tags: tlb, cpu-cache

I have a task to learn the number of ways in TLB-cache. Which algorithm should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"? It's not something that changes - its in silicon on your chip. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Flag this as "homework"?

Comment: I mean "to learn". I try to bypass array, but i havn't the result.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear as to what you need help with, so this is a summary of information related to the topics you mention.

There are two "ways" to get to memory - direct mapping, where the page table is kept in memory and is indexed by virtual page number. To translate from virtual page number to real page number the OS goes to the base address of the page table and adds the virtual page number. The value at this location gives the real address of the page.

The other way is associative mapping. Associative mapping keeps the page table in content-addressed memory, so when a virtual address is looked up, all the process's pages are searched in parallel giving O(1) lookup time complexity. Another advantage is that this stores only the pages that have been actually allocated.

The problem is that associative mapping requires special hardware to accomplish the content-addressed memory.

So the trade-off is that a small amount of content-addressed memory is used (a TLB = translation lookaside buffer which you refer to in your question), with the majority using direct mapping.

Then the big consideration is when to place an address in the TLB and which old one to evict from the TLB. For this there are many choices: most likely it will be Least Recently Used (LRU) to exploit temporal locality. Other choices could be Least Frequently Used, Round Robin (probably not very good here), WS_Clock, etc.